# Android Studio on Mac wrongly automatically cuts and pastes code/text

Tags: macos, android-studio

I do not know how to explain to you but whenever I try to type anything to the code editor of Android Studio on Mac, it turns out to be very crazy and funny. To make long story short, what I type is not what I see in the code editor as you can see in the video linked below:

https://youtu.be/tYh5keNHmk8

Thank you so much indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is a problem with the circuit and voltage difference on your mac computer and the keyboard which leads to this issue. I researched thoroughly on the internet but could not find any similar issue. In this case I would suggest you to try a new keyboard to see how it goes.

Comment: thanks mate for your clarification. i will give it a try like you said. i kept using Windows instead of Mac OS on the imac